# Remote Server: Permission denied (publickey) when using rsync with ssh with gpg via cronjob

Tags: ssh, cron, rsync, gpg

I want to do regular backups of my remote VPS via a cronjob. Both systems run Debian 10.
I have been following [this guide](https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/vps-backups-simple-overthinking/) and tweaked it to my liking. Relevant parts of the script:

`/root/.local/bin/backup`

```
#!/bin/bash

SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)

rsync -avzAHXh -e ssh root@[someIP]:/path/to/remote/dir /path/to/local/dir \
    || { echo "rsync died with error code $?"; exit 1; }
```

When I run this from the terminal, everything works fine. However if I run it via a cronjob:

`crontab -u root -e`

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  0 6  *    *    *   /root/.local/bin/backup >> /var/log/backup 2>&1
```

Then `/var/log/backup` shows:

```
root@[someIP]: Permission denied (publickey).^M
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.3]
rsync died with error code 12
```

What is going wrong in the cronjob and what can I do about it?

PS: I have deleted the passphrase for the gpg key I use here, trying to make this work. Ideally I would like a solution that works even when I add a passphrase again.

Comment: Is the SSH_AUTH_SOCK exported ?

Comment: Also, does `gpgconf` work in the very limited environment of cron?

Comment: It does work when I `export SSH_AUTH_SOCKET=[...]` :) Thanks @XTian :) Would you be willing to explain in an answer why this is necessary in this context, and why it isn't when I run it via the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands executed by Cron have an extremely basic execution environment and path setting, a frequent error is to test a command or script as your normal user id. Then it fails when run by Cron.

Exported Environment variables are often overlooked. It is prudent to do a final test, as root, with a completely cut down environment, as a final test, use a sub shell, before deployment. You can always add a one off cronjob, that simply prints it's env to a log file, this enables you to emulate the exact conditions your command will run with, when invoked by Cron. A second advantage, if any error occurs, is that it can be displayed on your terminal, it's easier to debug this way.

It looks like the variable assigned in your script is not exported, so SSH will not pick it up.

It's also important to use absolute file paths in a script, unless you change directory specifically, you can't assume you are in a particular directory, printing the working directory in the one-off test script, previously mentioned helps as well. You can not assume all distribution s are identical in this respect. It certainly doesn't hurt to check.